# Flask invalid Syntax in requests.get and messages

Tags: python

My code was working perfectly fine until last week. I am using Python3.5 and Flask '1.0.2'. Flask complained about two lines:
    response = requests.get(f'http://{node}/get_chain')
and
    response = {'message': f'This transaction will be added to Block {index}'}
The error messages are as the following:

```
response = requests.get(f'http://{node}/get_chain')
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and
        response = {'message': f'This transaction will be added to Block {index}'}
                                                                            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I attached more context below as a reference. Does anybody have a clue of what's happening? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.5 does not support string interpolation.

So, this expression:

```
f'http://{node}/get_chain'
```

Won't run. It's a syntax error.

Try changing it to something like:

```
'http://{}/get_chain'.format(node)
```

And:

```
response = {'message': f'This transaction will be added to Block {index}'}
```

Need to be changed to:

```
response = {'message': 'This transaction will be added to Block {}'.format(index)}
```

You could also try upgrading to Python 3.6 or greater.